# JavaScript Resource Management Design Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, load

As a web developer, a common problem I find myself tackling is waiting for something to load before doing something else. In particular, I often hide (using either `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` depending on the situation) elements while waiting for a background image or a CSS file to load.

Consider [this example](http://www.last.fm/music/Radiohead/In+Rainbows) from Last.FM. They overlay a semi-transparant PNG over each album art image so that it looks like it's inside a jewel-case. They let it load when it loads, so depending on your internet speed, you may see the art image by itself (without the overlay) temporarily. In this case, the album art looks fine without the jewel-case effect. But in similar situations, I have found that I don't want the user to see the site's design mangled as resources incrementally load. So, in rare cases I have hidden everything from the user until the whole kit and kaboodle has loaded. But this is often a pain to write out, and may force the user to wait for a pretty long time to see anything (besides "loading..." text).

I can think of (and have used on occasion) some obvious solutions/compromises:

1. Use some inline CSS so that as certain parts of the DOM load and render, they will immediately have the correct size/position/etc.
2. Immediately render the navigation part of the site, so that if the user wanted to use the current page purely to get somewhere else, they don't have to wait for the rest to load.
3. Load pixelated images first as placeholders for layout while lazy-loading higher quality images as replacements.
4. Something quirky like using a cute animated gif to distract the user during a "loading..." phase.
5. Show useful information as a reference while loading the full UI. (Something akin to [Gmail Inbox Preview](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/05/new-in-labs-inbox-preview.html), etc.)

(Sorry if my question was basically just asked and answered...)

Despite all of these ideas, I still find myself hoping there are better ways of doing some of these things. So I guess what I'm looking for is some inspiration and/or any creative ways of dealing with this problem that you guys may have seen out in the wild.

Comment: As for images: use CSS to set a class for the images that has a `background` property with an animated gif (load gif). That's probably the most painless way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem.  Your best bet is going to be optimizing the site to load faster.  Try [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow)

- Combine all your JS and CSS assets so there is only one request each.

  - There are numerous ways of doing this and a number of **asset packagers** exist for every web framework out there
- Make sure your Layout CSS is proccessed first
- **Minimize the number of images** in your site. Combining things and using CSS sprites helps a lot
- If that still isn't enough, you could put your layout and sizing CSS in the HTML file to ensure the browser processes it first before the linked CSS

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Asset packagers are a great tip. I forgot about those. As for the second bullet ("Make sure your Layout CSS is proccessed first"): to do this, one would need to hide elements while waiting for the CSS to load, no? The fourth bullet I am aware of (mentioned in answer). While this is a very good list, I'm still hoping to get some other creative ideas from the community.

Comment: No need to hide things, just ensure that either the layout CSS is the first CSS file to be loaded or that the text of the CSS in the HEAD of the HTML document, not linked.  Making two requests to the webserver (html and layout css) or one (html with embedded css) should be very quick.  If your page take a long time to load and shifts around while loading maybe you are depending on images for layout?